# SQL Server Timezone Change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 databases on the same SQL Server. Is it possible to have one in PST and the other in EST?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have them *both* as UTC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, The date/time is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running.

You could however have a custom UDF that you would call instead of getdate() and then do the timezone change in that UDF. You can also assign default values to columns with something like this

```
CREATE TABLE Test (Val DATETIME DEFAULT  dateadd(hh,-3,GETDATE()))
```

Now when you do an insert it will use the default

```
INSERT test DEFAULT VALUES

SELECT * FROM test
```

....this of course won't work on updates and also someone could update that value

If you want to use GMT then use `GETUTCDATE`

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not account for daylight savings time. The only way this can be accomplished is by having a table for the time zones as this example.
https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport

In newer SQL versions it's a lot easier but in older versions (2014 or older) there is no straightforward way to accomplish this.